# Loop through results from mysql, and sum values

Tags: php, mysql

I use a `while` loop to process table record like this:

```
$get_s = "SELECT * FROM sells ORDER BY sells_date";
if ($result = mysqli_query($AECONNECT, $get_s)) {
    while ($show_s = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $quantity = $show_s['sells_quantity'];
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($result); 
}
```

I have all my table records, and now I want to sum up all quantity fields , but I don't know how to do it.

For example, if I got 10 records quantity for records like `2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 6` etc, I would like to sum them like this: `2+1+5+1+3+6 = 18`

Comment: use in your query `SUM(sells_quantity) as  sumquantity` and access it as  `$show_s['sumquantity ']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do something in mysql - do it. Use `SUM` aggregation function:

```
$get_s = "SELECT SUM(sells_quantity) as sells_sum FROM sells ORDER BY sells_date";
if ($result = mysqli_query($AECONNECT, $get_s)) {
    $show_s = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $show_s['sells_sum'];
} 
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Still, if you need certain values of rows - you can count sum in a loop:

```
$get_s = "SELECT * FROM sells ORDER BY sells_date";
if ($result = mysqli_query($AECONNECT, $get_s)) {
    $total = 0;
    while ($show_s = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $quantity = $show_s['sells_quantity'];
        $total += $quantity; 
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($result); 
    echo $total;
}
```

But mysql `SUM()` is preferrable.

Comment: `$quantity` is useless in OPs current usage (overwritten on every iteration). If not using `SUM` I'd make the `quantity` an array then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php outside of the loop.